# LINQ - .Any for class type list<string> and class type string

Tags: linq

I have two classes

```
public class Cars
{
    public string Car{ get; set; }
    public List<string> CarEquipment{ get; set; }
}

public class Customers
{
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string OwnedEquipment{ get; set; }
}
```

I would like to check if any 'CarEquipment' from public List of string (class Cars) eqauls string public string 'OwnedEquipment' from class Customers (bool true of false)

the below query

```
(Cars.Select(x=>x.CarEquipment).Any(Customers.Select(x=>x.OwnedEquipment).Contains)
```

unfortunately dosent work beacuse  one of props is list of string

Comment: How are you calling `.Select()` on the *class* `Cars` and not on any kind of enumeration?  What version of `.Any()` are you trying to use that takes a collection and not a lambda function?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do in this line of code.

Comment: Im calling `.Select()` on list<Cars> where props from list <string> is implemented using other LINQ query.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and indicate the exact error you're getting, as well as describe the result you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check:

```cs
var cars = new List<Cars>()
{ 
    new Cars { Car = "c1", CarEquipment = new List<string> { "a" } }, 
    new Cars { Car = "c2", CarEquipment = new List<string> { "a" } }
};

var customers = new List<Customers>() { new Customers { OwnedEquipment = "a" } };

var matchingCars = cars.Where(car => customers.Any(customer => car.CarEquipment.Contains(customer.OwnedEquipment)));
```

- first filter with a condition (Where)
- the condition which customers' ownequipment match car's car quipment list (car => customers.Any(customer => car.CarEquipment.Contains(customer.OwnedEquipment)))